# Your Dynamic Links path prefix is not configured in firebase.json

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

We have configured a custom domain for the firebase dynamic link. Initially, it was working fine but after "Deploying" the "firebase.json" I'm getting the below error.

[image: Your Dynamic Links path prefix is not configured in firebase.json]

firebase.json looks like this.

{
"hosting": {
"public": "public",
"ignore": [
"firebase.json",
"**/.*",
"**/node_modules/**"
],
"appAssociation": "NONE",
"rewrites": [ {
"source": "/**",
"dynamicLinks": true
}
]
}
}

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Change appAssociation from `NONE` to `AUTO`.

Comment: Why?  It stops the error but why?

Comment: @MadMac By switching appAssociation to `AUTO`, Firebase automatically generates the `apple-app-site-association` file on deploy. You can change appAssociation to `NONE` if you want to manually include your own `apple-app-site-association` file.

Comment: It doesn't seem to do this at all for me. I have it set to AUTO and my custom file is included. If I set it to NONE it just has an error.